# What version of adaptive card is supported by Microsoft teams?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I want my bot to send and embed video on Microsoft teams.

I noticed [VideoCard is not supported by Microsoft teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-reference#cards-not-supported-in-teams).

So I tried using [AdaptiveCard, but noticed you need v1.1 to embed video](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Media.html).

However, when I send a message with version 1.1 I it sends a `undefined` message (just text saying undefined). With v1.0 I can send cards without issue (to embed images etc.). v1.1 works for me when using the emulator.

Does this mean Microsoft Teams only supports v1.0 of AdaptiveCard? Or is there a way to upgrade my bot?

Currently [AdaptiveCard is on version v1.2.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AdaptiveCards/) so it would be nice to upgrade.

Comment: Teams is currently 1.0 but actively working up uodating. Stay tuned. You can use this page to track what version works on which Host: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/resources/partners

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft Teams currently supports v1.0 of Adaptive Cards, with additional support for newer versions planned.

Comment: is there a way to know when it supports newer versions? e.g. release notes

Comment: We'll update this page when support is added: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/whats-new

Answer (score 1):

Only version 1.0 of Adaptive Cards is supported in teams, We are working on upgrade but we don't have timeline to share. Please have a look at [Card Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-reference#adaptive-card) for more information.